# Empty space in TinyMCE toolbar

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using latest stable release of TinyMCE 4. Initialization code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    plugins: "codesample hr lists preview anchor code visualblocks fullscreen",
    toolbar: ['alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify alignnone | styleselect formatselect | bold italic blockquote | link unlink',
        'bullist numlist anchor | image | preview | codesample | visualblocks fullscreen code'
    ],
    menubar: false,
    height: 600,
    codesample_languages: [
        {text: 'Java', value: 'java'},
        {text: 'Python', value: 'python'},
        {text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup'},
        {text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript'},
        {text: 'CSS', value: 'css'},
        {text: 'C', value: 'c'},
        {text: 'C++', value: 'cpp'}
    ]
});
```

This code gives the following result:

[image]

As you can see, there is an empty space in the first toolbar, but the second one is OK. How to fix this?

Comment: I am not getting any such type of issue 
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xVfaab

Comment: This would typically be due to some sort of CSS conflict with the page that includes TinyMCE.  If you remove all of your custom CSS does the issue go away?  Ideally you could create a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that shows the issue in action.

Comment: Seems to be Django admin bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem not related to Django. It would seem that the the menu items were picking up the float position of a previous floating element.  Wrap your textarea with a `style="clear:both;"`

```html
<div style="clear:both;">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```